Can I buy a Britrail Pass while already in the UK?
I'm residing in Germany and visiting the UK in the summer.
I do not know yet which Britrail pass I need, as the length of my vacation will be determined after I've already entered the UK.
Can I buy a Britrail pass while already in the country?

Sadly then no you can't.
From https://www.britrail.com/plan-your-trip/faqs/

Can I purchase a BritRail Pass when I am in Britain?
No. Please remember to buy your BritRail Pass before leaving your country, as BritRail Passes cannot be purchased when in Britain


Suspect in practice you might be able to buy them if you have a way of connecting through Germany, eg a server running at home you can connect through. However I'm in the UK and can confirm that the ACP Rail site does not show me passes for sale, and the International Rail site does not seem to support mobile-based passes. You can also consider an Interrail One-country Pass for the UK.
